# How to add and update rows in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable, rows

I am doing an online ordering system. I want to check if the item exist in the gridview so it will not add another row or have multiple lines (It will update the qty and the price). The gridview is updating using dgvOrder.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text but my problem is how to update the datatable.

```
bool isExist = false;
if (Session["dtInSession"] != null)
dt = (DataTable)Session["dtInSession"]; //Getting datatable from session
for (int i = 0; i < dgvOrder.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   if (dgvOrder.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text == b.ID)
   {
        isExist = true;
        dgvOrder.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(dgvOrder.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text) + 1);
        dgvOrder.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(dgvOrder.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text) * price);

    }
 }

 if (!isExist)
 {
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["pCode"] = b.ID;
    dr["desc"] = description;
    dr["qty"] = "1";
    dr["price"] = price;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dgvOrder.DataSource = dt;
    dgvOrder.DataBind();
  }
```

Because I am planning to pass the datatable using the session variable.

```
 Session["orders"] = dt;
 Response.Redirect("FinalizeOrder.aspx");
```

after passing the data, the code is working but only 1 qty for each item is passing.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: So `isExist` is getting set to true, but it's not incrementing the quantity?  Does it show as being incremented in the grid?

Comment: How large is the table going to be? I don't think it's the best idea to keep it in the session unless it is quite small.

Comment: The purpose of isExist is to check if the item is in the gridview. The gridview is updating but the datatable doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reload the `DataSource` of the `GridView` only if `!isExist`. Otherwise you are changing the datatable, but you are not assigning it to the `GridView` again, so the  values are coming from the `ViewState`.

So this should work:

```
// update the table
// ...
if (!isExist)
{
    // ...
}
// reassign the updated DataTable and DataBind the grid always
dgvOrder.DataSource = dt;
dgvOrder.DataBind();
```